# Resubscribe to takeUntil/skipUntil

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

The following code defines behavior i want (it works). Emmition of mousemove event occur only when mouse down.

```
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(window,"mouseup")
.subscribe( 
  () => {
      if(subscription)
         subscription.dispose();
  }
) 

Rx.Observable.fromEvent(window,"mousedown")
.subscribe(
  () => {
      subscription = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(window,"mousemove")
                     .subscribe(
                       (event) => console.log(event)
                     )
  }
)
```

I want to rewrite it using takeUntil/skipUntil operators. But this fails:

```
let fs =  [
  (e) => console.log(e),
  (err) => console.log(err),
  () => {
      console.log('done')  
      source.subscribe(...fs);
  }
 ];

let getDown = () => Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document,"mousedown");
let getUp = () => Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document,"mouseup");

let source = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document,"mousemove")
.skipUntil(getDown())
.takeUntil(getUp());

source.subscribe(
   ...fs
)
```

How i can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is generally solved by projecting each element of the trigger stream into the desired source stream and then flattening things out (which is usually achieved using `switchMap`). In this case, you want to project downs into moves until ups. Something like this:

```
const source = getDown().switchMap(() => Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, "mousemove").takeUntil(getUp());
```